# View patterns vs. pattern guards

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to get a sense of the relationship between view patterns and pattern guards in GHC. Pattern guards seem quite intuitive, while view patterns seem a bit confusing. It kind of looks like view patterns are better for dealing with things deep in a pattern, while pattern guards can reuse a view more intuitively, but I don't quite get it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

View patterns have significant overlap with pattern guards. The main advantage of view patterns is that they can be nested, and avoid introducing intermediate pattern variables. For a silly example:

```
endpoints (sort -> begin : (reverse -> end : _)) = Just (begin, end)
endpoints _ = Nothing
```

The pattern guard equivalent requires every new view to bind a new pattern variable, alternating between evaluating expressions and binding patterns.

```
endpoints xs
  | begin : sorted <- sort xs
  , end : _ <- reverse sorted
  = Just (begin, end)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

View patterns can also use only those variables bound earlier in the pattern, but it does look nice:

```
nonzero :: (a -> Int) -> a -> Maybe a
nonzero f (f -> 0) = Nothing
nonzero _ x = Just x

-- nonzero (fromEnum . not . null) "123" == Just "123"
--                                 ""    == Nothing
```

The main advantage of pattern guards is that they are a simple generalisation of guards, and can include ordinary Boolean expressions. I generally prefer them over view patterns because I find the style of `case` and guards less repetitious than the equational style.

Answer (score 8):

View patterns let you project a value before pattern matching on it. It can almost be thought of as a short cut for

```
 foo x = case f x of
   ...
```

There's a bit of sugar on top for dealing with more complex views, but basically that's it. On the other hand, pattern guards are strictly more general,

1. They can include arbitrary boolean conditions for matching
2. They can match using more than one of the variables

I favor view patterns when I'm doing something "lens-like". I have a big piece of data and I'm interested in one particular view of it. For example, with lens

```
foo (view someLens -> Bar baz quux) = ...
```

Pattern guards tend to work well when you want something closer to a more flexible case expression.