# Pattern match in function argument in haskell

Tags: haskell

In the code defining a function, there is a strange "pattern match"    `(cradleRootDir -> projdir)`

I guess that is meant to apply the function inline and binds the result to the name `projdir`.

What is the name of that construct ?

```
withGhcModEnv' :: (IOish m, GmOut m) => (FilePath -> (Cradle -> m a) -> m a) -> FilePath -> Options -> ((GhcModEnv, GhcModLog) -> m a) -> m a
withGhcModEnv' withCradle dir opts f =
    withCradle dir $ \crdl ->
      withCradleRootDir crdl $
        f (GhcModEnv opts crdl, undefined)
 where
   withCradleRootDir (cradleRootDir -> projdir) a = do
       cdir <- liftIO $ getCurrentDirectory
       eq <- liftIO $ pathsEqual projdir cdir
       if not eq
          then throw $ GMEWrongWorkingDirectory projdir cdir
          else a
```

The constructor

```
data Cradle = Cradle {
    cradleCurrentDir :: FilePath
  , cradleRootDir    :: FilePath
  , cradleCabalFile  :: Maybe FilePath
  , cradlePkgDbStack  :: [GhcPkgDb]
  } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: That is a view pattern. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20766841/2751851) for some interesting examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's using [View Patterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns)

> Evaluation To match a value v against a pattern (expr -> pat),
>   evaluate (expr v) and match the result against pat.

See [cabal file](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/blob/master/ghc-mod.cabal#L99)

```
Default-Extensions:   ScopedTypeVariables, RecordWildCards, NamedFieldPuns,
                      ConstraintKinds, FlexibleContexts,
                      DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeOperators, ViewPatterns
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                |  |  |  | |
```